# How many one-line expressions can make an array with integers from 0 to 99?

Tags: ruby

For example,

```
[0.99].to_a
# => [0, 1, 2, 3...]
```

I'm wondering how many different one-line solutions there are. This is how many I got (6):

```
(0..99).to_a
[*0..99]
0.upto(99).to_a
[*0.upto( 99 )]
(0..99).map {|a| a}
(0..100).step(1).to_a
```

Comment: This is a rather frivolous question as asked as it's not providing a useful set of answers. It's easy to generate minor variations and continue to come up with different ways to do this, but the majority would be mere curiosities or examples of ways we should never do it. Instead, a better question would ask for the most concise, fastest, or most efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

```
1. (0..99).to_a
2. (0..99).map{|e| e}
3. 1.upto(99).inject([]) { |sum, e| sum << e }
4. 1.upto(99).map { |e| e }
5. 99.times.inject([]) { |sum, e| sum << e.next}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do these:

```
1. (0..99).map { |a| a }

2. (0..99).step(1).to_a

3. (0..99).to_a

4. (1..99).each { |a| a }.to_a
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious one...

```
 Array.new(100) {|i| i}
 # the same as:
 Array.new(100, &:to_i)
```

And if we want to be stupid about it:

```
 Module.const_get([].class.name).new(100, &:to_i)
 eval("[1,2,3,*(4..99)]")
```